# Android leakcanary obfuscate

Tags: android, gradle, leakcanary

Confusion can't use leakcanary
LeakCanary plugin has been imported
java.lang.NullPointerException

have integrated Leakcanary for the first time in my app, The trace is generated like the following. Can someone explain to me what does it mean?

```
  2022-03-05 13:08:12.684 25896-25896/com.liangke.tingXieBen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.liangke.tingXieBen, PID: 25896
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at curtains.internal.WindowCallbackWrapper$Companion.getJetpackWrapped(:112)
        at curtains.internal.WindowCallbackWrapper$Companion.unwrap(:154)
        at curtains.WindowsKt.getWrappedCallback(:233)
        at leakcanary.RootViewWatcher$listener$1.onRootViewAdded(:46)
        at curtains.OnRootViewAddedListener$DefaultImpls.onRootViewsChanged(:38)
        at leakcanary.RootViewWatcher$listener$1.onRootViewsChanged(:43)
        at curtains.internal.RootViewsSpy$delegatingViewList$1.add(:25)
        at curtains.internal.RootViewsSpy$delegatingViewList$1.add(:23)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:403)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4535)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)




  debug {
        minifyEnabled true //注意测试的时候不要混淆
      //  testCoverageEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguardTest-rules.pro'
    }
```

[enter link description here](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#using-leakcanary-with-obfuscated-apps)

Comment: There's no obfuscation going on here, you have a clear crash.  Leak canary called some library called curtains that deals with window events, which ended up with an internal crash.  If you want to debug further, I'd look at the curtains source code, it is open sourced.

Comment: Sorry for not being detailed enough yesterday

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367145/android-leakcanary-obfuscate-plugin-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same crash log because I enabled:

```
minifyEnabled
```

in debug mode. The solution is adding:

```
-keep class androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper { *; }
```

in your progurd rules.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have successfully implemented

Comment: 在没有使用这个插件前，没有任何泄露，为何使用了这个插件检测出来很多泄露